# Black UV editor

Tags: uv

Im **very** new to blender, so im watching a begginer tutorial series on blender, but i ran into a problem, my UV editor is just a black screen and doesen't display the actual UV map of the object i have selected.

I imagine there is probably a really simple solution to this, but as i said im very new to blender, only starting to learn it yesterday so i dont know anything about nothing yet, any help is greatly apreciated.
[image: The black UV editor]

Comment: The black area is most probably a texture, which covers the UV space from 0 to 1. Have you tried to zoom out in the UV editor? This can be for example done with the scroll wheel. And for the wire not displaying, when the mesh isn't uv mapped yet, then there is of course nothing to display. - EDIT, hmm, the image editor shows the NEW Button in the header. So there is no texture active here. Maybe you have a graphics card driver problem?

Comment: Another thought. The orange buttons tells me that this is not the default theme. Maybe the theme is broken? Could you please switch back to the default theme and have a look if things looks different then?

Comment: try this: move the mouse pointer to the UV editor on the left and press the 'A' key. If everything turns yellow/orange then your mesh is so dense that the outlines of the UV islands cover everything with black. Try to zoom out as suggested and you will see a black square.

Comment: People might be able to help you more if you provided a link to the file somewhere.